# Buildroot - Error building jamvm 1.5.1

Tags: zlib, buildroot, jamvm

I've got (another) build error when trying to build my Buildroot environment. Note this question is in relation to (but not dependent on) my previous (resolved) questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101901/unrecognized-option-o-could-not-create-the-java-virtual-machine) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142685/buildroot-applying-a-patch-failed).

I'm trying to include Bluetooth support in the kernel as well as JamVM , but I have ALREADY succesfully built a Buildroot environment which includes Jamvm but now for some reason the build is failing.

When the build process gets to:

> > > jamvm 1.5.1 Configuring

It eventually fails with the error:

> checking for ecj... (cached) javac
> -Xlint:unchecked,cast,divzero,empty,finally,overrides
>
> checking for pthread_self in -lpthread... yes
>
> checking for fmod in -lm... yes
>
> checking for dlopen in -ldl... (cached) yes
>
> checking for inflate in -lz... yes
>
> checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
>
> checking for sys/time.h... (cached) yes
>
> checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
>
> checking endian.h usability... yes
>
> checking endian.h presence... yes
>
> checking for endian.h... yes
>
> checking for sys/param.h... (cached) yes
>
> checking for locale.h... (cached) yes
>
> checking for zlib.h... (cached) no
>
> configure: error: zlib.h is missing

I've checked the output location /output/build/zlib-1.2.3 and I can see the file zlib.h so I'm puzzled as to why make claims to be unable to find it. Also I altered jamvm.mk to depend upon zlib and tried make again (note I did not do a 'make clean')

Anyone have any ideas? I don't understand why jamvm won't build now, other than it must be something in the build process.

Comment: Also having this problem... even added the zlib.h directory to `PATH` and tried referencing it directly with `./configure --includedir=[my_path]`

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I put `zconf.h` header file into my toolchain include folder and the zlib missing configuration error message is gone.
give it a try.